# Remove characters from file name - between [ and ]

Tags: rename, regex

i download videos from YouTube for my hobby. The filenames contain some random characters between the [ and ]. E.g. filename [vbnghztresku].webm.

My partial solution starts as follows:

find /medien -type f -name "*.webm" -exec rename  ????????

However I a have difficulties for the regular Expression part of the command.

Could some experienced user guide me to working solution, please ?

Best regards, Bleckie

Answer (score 0):

`[` and `]` are metacharacters in regular expression syntax - to match them literally, they must be escaped. So for example:

```
$ rename -n 's/ \[.*?\]//' *.webm
rename(filename [vbnghztresku].webm, filename.webm)
```

Comment: Well steeldriver, thanks for your suggestion. I completed my script with your suggested extension and ran the following completed script: find /medien -type f -name "*.webm" -exec rename -n 's/ \[.*?\]//' *.webm  {} +. However it failed to do the proposed conversion. What went wrong ? I really appreciate your kind suggestion. regards, Bleckie